# How to search values inside a List in SQL Server stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the next SQL stored procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Txt_Split(
    @userId INT,
    @List varchar(MAX), -- List of changes
    @Delimiter char(3) = '", "' -- delimiter that separates items
 )
 AS 
 BEGIN
     DECLARE @deviceId AS INT
     DECLARE @variableId AS INT
     DECLARE @variables AS varchar(max)
     DECLARE @Item Varchar(MAX)
     CREATE TABLE #List(Item varchar(MAX)) -- Create a temporary table
     DECLARE @l TABLE(v VARCHAR(4000))
     DECLARE @2 TABLE(a VARCHAR(4000))

     SET NOCOUNT ON

     --BEGIN
     WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,0) <> 0
     BEGIN
         SELECT
         @Item=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List,2,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,
            @List,0 )-2))),

         @List=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,
            @List,0)+2,LEN(@List))))

         IF LEN(@Item) > 0
         INSERT INTO #List SELECT @Item

         INSERT INTO @l SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@Item, ',');

    --Get deviceIds
         SET @deviceId = (
          SELECT MAX(REPLACE(v, 'deviceId=', '')) --easy way of getting the value
          FROM @l                                 --from values list
          WHERE v LIKE 'deviceId=%'               --where "deviceId" is the key we want
        );
     PRINT @deviceId

     --Get variablesIds

        SET @variables = (
          SELECT MAX(REPLACE(v, '', '')) --easy way of getting the value
          FROM @l                               --from values list
          WHERE v LIKE 'variableId=%'               --where "deviceId" is the key we want
        );

        INSERT INTO @2 SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@variables, ' ');

        SET @variableId = (
          SELECT MAX(REPLACE(a, 'variableId=', '')) --easy way of getting the value
          FROM @2                               --from values list
          WHERE a LIKE 'variableId=%'               --where "deviceId" is the key we want
        );
        PRINT @variableId

     END

     IF LEN(@List) > 0
     INSERT INTO #List SELECT @List -- Put the last item in
     INSERT INTO @l SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@List, ',');

     SET @deviceId = (
          SELECT MAX(REPLACE(v, '"deviceId=', '')) --easy way of getting the value
          FROM @l                                 --from values list
          WHERE v LIKE '"deviceId=%'               --where "deviceId" is the key we want
        );
     PRINT @deviceId

     --Comprobar


        --PRINT @userId


     select * from @l
     select * from @2
     DROP TABLE #List
     RETURN
 END
 GO
         EXEC sp_Txt_Split  @userId=4, @List='"deviceId=1,variableId=26 idTemperatura=97 1543502040725018880", "deviceId=1,variableId=1 idTemperatura=93 
     1543502040725018880", "deviceId=1,variableId=26 idTemperatura=97 1543502040725018880"'
```

There I have all the Strings:
the first is: `"deviceId=1,variableId=26 idTemperatura=97 1543502040725018880"`.

I can extract `deviceId` correctly but the `variableId` is always printing the same.

Comment: Change the `@list` to something that SQL Server could parse... like JSON or XML.

Comment: Personally, i would switch from using a delimited string to a Table Type parameter, or (like @SalmanA mentioned) valid XML or JSON data (If you aren't using SQL Server 2016+ then probably not JSON).

Comment: @SalmanA Why I can't use a simple list of Strings?

Comment: @Larnu is not possible getting the information of the simple List?

Comment: @AsierGomez good luck writing your own parser then,

Comment: Consider passing the list of strongly-typed structured data a [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters). That could be used directly in T-SQL without parsing.

Comment: The list might be "simple" for a human, but SQL Server isn't a human. it works with specifics. If you can't provide a list in a format it already accepts (table-type parameter, XML, JSON), then you need to build a parser. Why build a parser when the far better option is to use a readily available format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I use variables, so I take the values using CHARINDEX:

```
 set @device = (SELECT RIGHT(@Item, LEN(@Item) - CHARINDEX('deviceId=', @Item)-8));
 set @device = (SELECT LEFT(@device, CHARINDEX(',', @device, 0) - 1));

 set @variable = (SELECT RIGHT(@Item, LEN(@Item) - CHARINDEX('variableId=', @Item)-10));
 set @variable = (SELECT LEFT(@variable, CHARINDEX(' ', @variable, 0) - 1));

 set @deviceId = (select cast(@device as int))
 set @variableId = (select cast(@variable as int))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Table Valued parameter instead of `varchar`, then all will be easy to do

```
CREATE Type MyType AS TABLE
(DeviceID INT, VariableID INT);

CREATE PROCEDURE isUserAllowed
  @UserID INT,
  @List MyType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  /*
    Do what ever you need
  */
END

DECLARE @T MyType;

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 2);

EXEC isUserAllowed 1, @T;
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with SQL Server 2016 (And also in SQLAzure) you can break a string into a table, based on a delimiter, using the STRING_SPLIT function.

It takes a string, and a delimiter and returns a TABLE. Link to docs at the end:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE isUserAllowed
    @userId INT,
    @List VARCHAR(MAX)
 AS
 BEGIN
    DECLARE @userReadLevel AS INT
    DECLARE @variableReadLevel AS INT
    DECLARE @deviceReadLevel AS INT

    SET nocount ON

    DECLARE @l TABLE(v VARCHAR(4000));

    --Let's assume your list is comma sep key value pairs like: deviceId=123,blahId=456,someId=789
    --string_split is only available in db compatibility version 130+
    --You must have SQLS2016+ and be set to 130 or higher!!
    INSERT INTO @l SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@list, ',');

    SET @deviceReadLevel = (
      SELECT MAX(REPLACE(v, 'deviceId=', '')) --easy way of getting the value
      FROM @l                                 --from values list
      WHERE v LIKE 'deviceId=%'               --where "deviceId" is the key we want
    );

    --and so on..
    SET @... = (...)
    SET @... = (...)

    SELECT
        CASE 
           WHEN (@userReadLevel <= @deviceReadLevel) and (@userReadLevel <= @variableReadLevel) 
              THEN 1
           WHEN (@userReadLevel > @deviceReadLevel) or (@userReadLevel > @variableReadLevel) 
              THEN 0
        END AS allowed
    END



EXEC isUserAllowed  @userId=4, @List='["deviceId=1,variableId=26", "deviceId=1,variableId=1"]'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017